# Why am I getting a UNIQUE Constraint Failure in my SQLite3 table

Tags: linux, sqlite, constraints

I have been searching StackOverflow, SQLite.com, and Google for help, but haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

I need to combine two older tables into one new table, but the PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints seem to be fighting with each other (I am getting a Constraint Failed error once it gets to the INSERT statement).  The script will run if I remove the UNIQUE constraint, but then I have duplicate CamIndex records.

```
CREATE TABLE tmpTable(
RowID      INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
CamIndex   INTEGER   UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
LenIndex   INTEGER   NOT NULL,
CamDesc    TEXT,
LenDesc    TEXT
);

INSERT INTO tmpTable(
CamIndex,
LenIndex,
CamDesc,
LenDesc
)

SELECT
TblA.CAM_INDEX,
TblB.LEN_INDEX, 
TblA.CAM_DESC,
TblB.LEN_DESC

FROM TblA
LEFT JOIN TblB on TblA.CAM_INDEX = TblB.CAM_INDEX;
```

How do I make the CamIndex column UNIQUE and keep RowID as Primary key?

This didn't work either:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpTable(
RowID      INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
CamIndex   INTEGER   NOT NULL, 
LenIndex   INTEGER   NOT NULL,
CamDesc    TEXT,
LenDesc    TEXT,
UNIQUE(CamIndex)
);
```

I'm using SQLite so I can't add the UNIQUE constraint with the ALTER Table statement.

Comment: Inspect your `SELECT` statement.  Are you getting back the same `CamIndex` for any different `LenIndex`, `CamDesc`, or `LenDesc`?  That's *likely* what's breaking you.

Comment: If I remove the UNIQUE constraint (so the script will run), I am getting the same CamIndex for different LenIndex records.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption about the uniqueness of your data is invalid.  Given what you had remarked in the comments, the result of your `SELECT` statement produces the same `CamIndex` for different combinations of `LenIndex`, `CamDesc`, or `LenDesc`.  Given that, you cannot place a unique constraint on `CamIndex`.

You will need to reevaluate your SELECT query to ensure that you're not getting bogus values from it before you can constrain your table.

Comment: Yes, thank you for helping me see that.  Back to the drawing board!